# Handling exception at a controller method signature

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-post

I have a `POST` request whose request body taken in several parameters. On the server side, the request body is mapped to a POJO.

In case, I don't send any request body, the server throws an error. When I use the annotation `@RequestBody(required = false)`, the request body is mapped to a `null` object. I can validate it and send appropriate response.

But in the case, when I send an empty json - `{ }` in the request body, it gets mapped to a `not null` object with all its attributes set as null. Nothing unexpected. All the attributes must be `non null`, so I have set an attribute - `@NotNull` (imported from `org.springframework.lang.NonNull`). Now if I send an empty json `{ }`, I get 500 response with the exception as follows.

```
2019-08-25 21:49:21.921 ERROR 28538 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class package.model.Model]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `package.model.Model`, problem: someAttribute is marked non-null but is null
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 1]] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: someAttribute is marked non-null but is null
```

I want to catch the exception and send a `200` response code with an appropriate response body. How do I do that? Or is there another way to check not null attributes?

Basically I want that the request body attributes must have all the attributes, otherwise I want to return a custom built error response.

Comment: "*I want to catch the exception and send a 200 response code with an appropriate response body.*" - Don't do that. You should return a HTTP Error 400 (Bad request).

Comment: Currently it gives a 500 response. I have no control over its behaviour as of now. How do I even send a 400 response

Comment: Maybe [this baelung article](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) helps.

Comment: If you have a look at the article that @Turing85 has attached and head to the section 4, Solution 3 - you will find a very useful ControllerAdvice example. It's what I personally use and would advice you to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to use `@ControllerAdvice`. It works like "watching" your application.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomizedExceptionHandler  {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class) // change here for your exception.
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleUserNotFoundException(NotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = ErrorDetails.builder()
                .timestamp(new Date())
                .message(ex.getMessage())
                .details(request.getDescription(false))
                .build();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN); // you can return whatever you want.
    }

}
```

PS: Note that your exception is a `NullPointerException`, a very common exception, every null pointer that your application throws will be handled by your customized controller.

Comment: @uneq95 Glad to help ;D